# how to decrypt the data received by the soql in controller?

Tags: soql, decrypt

The is the query----

```
SELECT Name
,SVMXC__Company__c
,SVMXC__Component__c
,SVMXC__Product__c 
,SVMXC__Scheduled_Date_Time__c
,SVMXC__Zip__c
,SVMXC__City__c
,SVMXC__Priority__c,SVMXC__Order_Status__c 
FROM SVMXC__Service_Order__c 
where Name=:param1
```

I need the value of SVMXC__Product__c which is returning a string like `01t3h000000Pl3TAAS`, how can i convert this value.The following code I have tried but getting errors.

```
Blob data = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(order.SVMXC__Product__c);
Blob decryptedData = Crypto.decrypt('AES128', key, encrypted, encrypted);
String dryptData = decryptedData.toString();
System.debug(dryptData);
```

Comment: I have to admit it's the first time in my life that I've ever seen someone ask to decrypt a Salesforce ID :D

Comment: You may find value in completing some introductory Trailhead modules, such as [Apex Basics and Database](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database), to help alleviate confusion with the core concepts of the Salesforce platform and let yourself move faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a record ID and doesn't require decrypting. What are you trying to do? Do you want the name of the product? If so `SVMXC__Product__r.Name` is what you need in the query instead. Please read the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm) about the Salesforce object model and how to use it in SOQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot Phil...Using SVMXC__Product__r.Name now I am able to retrieve the data I need.